# table update locking from vbscript

Tags: mysql, vbscript, locking

From a table like this:

```
ID  SEQUENCE
1    1
```

I want to increment the sequence value each time the table is accessed. So far I came up with this vbscript:

```
Dim Result
On Error Resume Next
Result = GetSequential()
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("result_" & Result & ".txt", False)
if err.Number <> 0 then
   MsgBox err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & "): " & Result
end if
on error goto 0
wscript.echo "Next value: " & Result

Function GetSequential()
Dim cn, rs
Dim Sequential

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.connectionstring = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver};Server=172.16.0.130;Database=testautostore;User=root;Password=aquilae"
cn.Open

Dim SqlCount
SqlCount = "select count(*) from counter where ID='1'"
rs.Open SqlCount, cn, adOpenStatic

If rs(0) = "1" Then 
    wscript.echo "Updating record..."
    Dim SqlUpdate
    SqlUpdate = "update counter set SEQUENCE=SEQUENCE + 1 where ID='1'"
    cn.Execute SqlUpdate

    Dim SqlSelect
    SqlSelect = "select SEQUENCE from counter where ID='1'"
    rs.Close
    rs.Open SqlSelect, cn, adOpenStatic

    Sequential = rs(0)
    wscript.echo "Result: " & Sequential
End if

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close

GetSequential = Sequential
End Function
```

This works fine when run individually:

```
cscript testsequence.vbs
```

but when running it several times simultaneously then is not guaranteed to get a unique sequence number. This is apparent when launching a batch file like this:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 25) do start cscript testsequence.vbs
```

which produces exception failures when creating the result_?.txt files as a result of returning the same sequence value (File already exists).

So the question is how can I lock the table update operation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to assume that the update and read in your script will be atomic:

- process A updates `sequence`
- process A reads `sequence`
- process B updates `sequence`
- process B reads `sequence`

MySQL, however, has autocommit enabled by default, so each statement is run by itself, and queries from concurrent processes may become intermingled:

- process A updates `sequence`
- process B updates `sequence`
- process B reads `sequence`
- process A reads `sequence`

That way A and B will read the same value, although both processes incremented it.

You need to put your statements in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) and use an appropriate [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html).

Comment: Thank you, now it works fine just by enclosing the update-select operations between cn.Execute "start transaction" and cn.Execute "commit". Not sure though where should I put a cn.Execute "rollback"...

Comment: Probably nowhere. A `rollback` cancels a transaction and rolls back everything that the transaction has changed so far. Hence the name.